# How to fix: Python missing error, python3 (>= 3.7~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies, ppa, python3

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grapejuice : Depends: python3 (>= 3.7~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I was all fine about python3 dependency as needed but at the end, I encountered this error.

Does anyone know how to fix this? This may have to do with the ppa repository or python. I should get an answer to this as a solution.

Comment: Please don't forget Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reaches the end of it's *five years* of *standard* support in April 2023 (2018-April + 5 years); so consider *release-upgrading* to a later release (*which will have `python3` that meets the requirements*).

Comment: What do you mean by this release-upgrading to a later release?

Comment: *release-upgrading* is how I write up the execution of `do-release-upgrade` & like commands, to upgrade you from 18.04 to 20.04